# Return relation if it counts greater than 0 else return other relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to return a relation if it has results greater than 0 otherwise it should return other relation

```
public function default_product_image()
    {  
        if(count($this->ztecpc_product_images()->get()) > 0)
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\ZtecpcProductImage','product_id','id')//if count > 0 then return this relation
                    ->select('id','product_id','image');
        }
        return $this->hasOne('App\ProductImagesModel','product_id','id')//else return this relation
                    ->where('main_image',1)
                    ->select('id','product_id','image');
    }

 public function ztecpc_product_images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ZtecpcProductImage','product_id','id')
                    ->select('id','product_id','image');
    }
```

I want to return `return $this->hasMany('App\ZtecpcProductImage','product_id','id')
                    ->select('id','product_id','image');` if `ztecpc_product_images` relation has the results greater than 0 otherwise it should return other relation in the function. My problem is that it is always return empty array which I guess it the if-condition `if(count($this->ztecpc_product_images()->get()) > 0)` is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Change your if statement like that:

```
if($this->ztecpc_product_images()->count() > 0)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214465/discussion-on-answer-by-urudin-return-relation-if-it-counts-greater-than-0-else).

Answer (score 0):

I think your guess is correct and I believe I know why:

```
$this->ztecpc_product_images
```

Will return an Eloquent Collection rather than an array. This is an object and will always return true even if empty.

Try replacing it with the following:

```
if ($this->ztecpc_product_images->isNotEmpty()) {
   ...
}
```

This uses the available Eloquent Collection methods to check for a lack of results.